# Unexpected token ( error

Tags: javascript

hello can anyone help me debug little error that my eyes seem to be skipping. error is: unexpected ( error. Are my array syntex correct?

```
function SourceClusting()
{
    // grabbing count
    var table = document.getElementById('OSDataCount');
    var counter= table.rows[1].children[0].innerHTML
    // putting all variable into arrays
    var latitude()
    var longitude()
    var i

    var marker =[];

    // placing values into arrays
    for (i=1;i == counter;i++)
        {
        longitude[i]=table.rows[i].children[6].innerHTML;
        latitude[i]=table.rows[i].children[5].innerHTML;

        marker[i]=new GMarker(new GLatLng(longitude[i],latitude[i])); 

        }

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, marker);


}
```

cheers

Comment: try using jslint.com to check syntax

Comment: var latitude() var longitude() ? are these variables? try removing the () and replacing with a ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few things:

- You have to `parseInt()` the string you get from `var counter = ...`, as a string can't be used in comparisons with integers the way you'd like.
- `var latitude = ()` should be `var latitude = []`, as it's an array, Don't forget those semicolons!
- You usually use a lesser-than sign in a loop, not an equality sign `==`.
- You can condense the loop by initializing `i` within it.

Try this new, possibly working code:

```
function SourceClusting() {
    // grabbing count
    var table = document.getElementById('OSDataCount');
    var counter= parseInt(table.rows[1].children[0].innerHTML, 10);
    // putting all variable into arrays
    var latitude = [];
    var longitude = [];

    var marker =[];

    // placing values into arrays
    for (var i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
        longitude[i]=table.rows[i].children[6].innerHTML;
        latitude[i]=table.rows[i].children[5].innerHTML;

        marker[i]=new GMarker(new GLatLng(longitude[i],latitude[i])); 

        }

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, marker);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problems are in these lines:

```
var latitude()
var longitude()
```

You mean

```
var latitude;
var longitude;
```

or possibly

```
var latitude = [];
var longitude = [];
```

since you seem to be treating them as arrays.

Comment: This will then error when the line starting `longitude[i]=` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

`var latitude()` is nonsense. I suspect you mean `var latitude = [];`

(With a similar correction for the following line)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to instantiate an array, instead of:

```
var latitude();
```

it should be:

```
var latitude = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare var latitidue(), but that doesn't make anysense. Hence the unexpected '('. Also, missing semi-colon after statement.